# HttpApplication.Application_Start not firing after upgrade to Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I upgraded an application to Web Api 2 and the Application_Start would not fire post upgrade running on IIS Express. I did follow the official upgrade path at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2 and have triple checked my settings.

The application uses StructureMap MVC 4 to inject dependencies. So WebActivator's PreApplicationStartMethod gets fired and the dependency resolver gets set correctly. After that, no other execution can be traced. I have enabled Edit and Continue and yet break point at the start of Application_Start is not hit.

Here's all that I've tried:
a. Disable PreApplicationStartMethod and run the app
b. Change the compile settings of the Global.asax and the code behind
c. Create another WebApi2 project with similar structure and set up minus the actual code and that works fine

I have cleaned and run the app; also have cleaned the Temp ASP.NET folder

Appreciate the help towards resolving this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Your debugger attaches after your application is started, therefor you won't hit any breakpoints in your application start method. A workaround is to cause your webserver to restart while you're attached to the process:

Simply edit your web.config (just add a space) and save it, this will make your http application restart.

Comment: I am aware of this; I did miss mentioning that when I try to edit the global file, Edit Continue dialog says that the assembly is not loaded. I'm going to remove the global file, close the solution, re-add and see what happens.

Comment: ah! sorry, misread your reply. It says I have to stop my debugging session when I attempt to save the web.config file even though I have enabled Edit & Continue. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: I guess I can explore more and pursue. Interestingly, the break point in the Application_Start of the new api app gets hit every single time with no changes to web.config made.

Answer (score 2):

Put a `Debugger.Break();` statement in your Application_Start, and then do an `iisreset` or recycle your app pool, then hit F5. A Just in time debugger window should appear if a breakpoint  doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure IIS Express is shut down, then F5 again to see if Application_Start is hit.

Comment: I've done that already - did not help. For kicks, I changed the port to run the app on and tried and that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem.
The global.asax.cs method `Application_Start()` had no parameters.
Once I added the standard ones `Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)` the method got hit.