# How to inject ApplicationUserManager with unity

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2

I have `ApplicationUserManager` defined like this:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>
    { 
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int> store)
        : base(store)
        {
        }

       public override Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password)
        {
            var result = base.CreateAsync(user, password);
            //... 
            Repository.DoSomething(...); //Repository is null here
            //..
        }          

       [Dependency]
       public IRepository Repository { get; set; }
    }
```

For some reason my repository in not getting injected. `Repository` is always `null`

I also have this line in my unity configuration

```
.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
```

How to make it injected?

**UPDATE N**:

This is code from my controller; How I am getting `UserManager`:

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
         //calling my implemintation
         IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(...);
    }
```

My current unity config

```
.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>, CustomUserStore>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(new InjectionFactory(o => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication))
.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>, ApplicationUserManager>()
.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor())
.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>()
```

**UPDATE N+1**:

As I find out `Unity.Mvc` package is not injecting WebApi controllers. I used this [method](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection) in order to inject WebApi controllers. I was trying to remove `Unity.Mvc` package but got `Identity` throwing errors. From my understanding because `Unity` was not able to instantiate some `Identity types` however they were being configured and worked in the case of setting `Mvc` container.
So I brought back the `Unity.Mvc` package to inject my `Identity types`. Otherwise, as I explained above, it is throwing different kind on null refs when `Unity` resolving `Identity types`.

So I have two containers now in my project `Unity.Mvc` injection `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));` that needed to resolve `Identity types` and custom `WebApi` injection `config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);` container that needed to inject `WebApi` contorllers both using same UnityConfig.

**UPDATE 3:**

I've changed 
this:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>());
```

to this

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>());
```

in `Startup.ConfigureAuth()` and now I my WebApi container is fully working and constructing all required `Identity types` so I can disable Mvc container or even completely can remove `Unity.Mvc` package.

Thanks to @Sam Farajpour Ghamari for clerifying lots of things.

Comment: How you access `ApplicationUserManager` object instance?

Comment: @SamFarajpourGhamari yes I can enter to debug my custom `CreateAsync()` method. But `Repository` is not injected and equal to `null`

Comment: Do you get instance of the object by calling `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>()` method?

Comment: @SamFarajpourGhamari Trying to call `var temt = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();` but got error 'No owin.Environment item was found in the context.'

Comment: I want to know how you get instance of ApplicationUserManager itself. Could you submit relevent code?

Comment: OK `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();` wasnt working when I try to call that in 'UnityConfig.cs' but it is working if I am calling it in `Controller`. So there is no issues with 'No owin.Environment...` I updated question wiht the code.

Comment: @SamFarajpourGhamari Do you have anything to say about my UPDATE 3 ? Why it is working after that change?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since you are using `UserManager` with OWIN. You need to integrate OWIN container with unity. Where as I don't see your other part of codes specially OWIN startup method. I show a simple example to demonstrate how you can do this by own.

First if you are using Entity Framework you must register your context to unity. Second register other type which Identity need them like this:

```
container.RegisterType<DbContext, MyDbContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>,
    UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(
    new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication))
container.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

Then change constructor of `ApplicationUserManager` like this:

```
public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store,
    IRepository repo)
        : base(store)
{
    this.Repository=repo;
    // put your other configuration here instead of putting in 
    // static ApplicationUserManagerCreate() method.
    this.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this)
    {
        AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
        RequireUniqueEmail = true
    };
        // Configure validation logic for passwords
    this.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
    {
        RequiredLength = 6,
        RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
        RequireDigit = true,
        RequireLowercase = true,
        RequireUppercase = true,
    };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
    this.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
    this.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    this.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

    // and your other configurations
}
```

Now in your `Startup.ConfigureAuth()` method change following lines:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(EFDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
    // others
}
```

to:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(()=> DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>());
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(()=> DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationSignInManager>());
    // other configs
}
```

Also we don't need `ApplicationUserManager Create()` and `ApplicationSignInManager.Create()` methods anymore and we could easily remove them, since Unity takes responsibility of create our classes now.

Now we fully integrate Identity with unity. For further and complex information I deeply encourage you to read [this awesome blog post](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/).

Comment: I am creating `ApplicationUserManager` like this: `var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new CustomUserStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));` - that is code from `IdentityConfig.cs`. How would it chnage it if I alter constructor method like you say above?

Comment: Are you creating your user manager inside of static  `ApplicationUserManager.Create()` method?

Comment: Since we want Unity creates user manager actually we don't need `ApplicationUserManager.Create()` method anymore. Simply copy your configuration from that method to constructor a `ApplicationUserManager` except `var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new CustomUserStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));` line since useless now

Comment: Yes it is gets created inside `ApplicationUserManager.Create()`

Comment: `Simply copy your configuration from that method to constructor...?` I guess I didn't get it.

Comment: Our goal is to remove `ApplicationUserManager.Create()` method from our code. If you have some code inside of that method, rather than `var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new CustomUserStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()))`; line. Move them to constructor of `ApplicationUserManager` class. See my updated post I show some example as a clue.

Comment: And your Unity configuration is fine now. Just need you change OWIN start up file also.

Comment: `app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>());` giving me null reference exeption

Comment: Please look and say exactly which object is null. If `Current` is null. it means you have not configured Unity bootstrapper well.

Comment: I didn't find yet where error is trowing. Here is error pritnscreen http://snag.gy/tSte4.jpg. I set breakpoint on `UnityConfig.RegisterComponents()` and on `Startup.ConfigureAuth()` but error getting throwed before these two. Also I set breakpoint on `Application_Start()` but it hasn't being excuted either. So I cant check what is exactly `null`.

Comment: If i uncomment `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create)` insteard `app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>());` so this way I didnt have `null` error.

Comment: I think Unity is configured **after** `Startup.ConfigureAuth()` called. And cause that error. Which unity package have you installed? `Unity.MVC` or other ones like `Unity.MVC4`?

Comment: I have two unity packages installed in my `WebApi 2` project: `Unity 3.5.140` and `Unity.WebApi 5.0.1`

Comment: Currently using this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692981/httpapplication-application-start-not-firing-after-upgrade-to-web-api-2 to debug. Now I have actually to edit web.config so debugger can hit app configuraton methods I was trying to debug above

Comment: Now I can see in debugger that `DependencyResolver.Current` - is not `null` but `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>()` returning `null`

Comment: Also based on my research I can clearly see that Unity configured before `Startup.ConfigureAuth()` - it is called straight after all lines in `Application_Start()` is executed and `UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();` is configured in `Application_Start()` so `UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();`  is gets called first

Comment: Does that means that Unity can't create `ApplicationUserManager` which is configured like that `.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>(new InjectionFactory(o => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()))`?  Also I tried that `.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())` but got same `null` exeption in `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>()`

Comment: That is is two top lines of my `ConfigureAuth()` now: `public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            //app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>()); }`

Comment: first of all in `ConfigureAuth()` method remove `app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create)` and `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create‌​)` we don't need them anymore. But for discovering error replace `app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>());` line with `app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>());` line. this cause we see actual exception insisted of  null object.

Comment: See [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870021/cannot-figure-out-why-unity-is-not-injecting-identity-dbcontext-properly/31874084#31874084) for more info

Comment: Also I deeply encourage you use official `Unity.MVC` package instead of  others. Don't worry `Unity.MVC` works well in WebAPI too. See [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235660/unity-inject-dependencies-into-mvc-filter-class-with-parameters/32248584#32248584) related for this issue.

Comment: OK I was being confused with the Unity.WebApi package name. I thought it is varsion for WebApi. So I changed that to Unity.Mvc then I puth the line  `UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>()` and now it is throwing an exeption `Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll` and referencing to `.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>(new InjectionFactory(o => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()))` with details `No owin.Environment item was found in the context`

Comment: Just added this `.RegisterType<IOwinContext> (new InjectionFactory(o => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()))`  to my Unity config - but no luck

Comment: Why you put  `RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>(new InjectionFactory(o => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()))` in your unity config? Please relook my answer I did not say that.

Comment: Unity.MVC is not injecting controllers in case of WebApi. I used this mehtod in order to inject WebApi controllers http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection But Unity.MVC is actualy needed to inject Idenity stuff. So I have both things in my project Mvc injection `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));` that needed to resolve Identity stuff and WebApi injection `config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);` that needed to inject WebApi contorllers both using same UnityConfig

Comment: How could i do to use this approach in 3 layerd application?

Comment: @Kob_24 noting special. All rules could be easily applied to 3 layered applications as well. Unity's configuration class actually is your composition root so you could layer your class, including Identity's classes, in any way you want and wire them in the Unity container.

Comment: @SamFarajpourGhamari Its not working for me actually, any tutorial about it?