# The current types, IUserStore<ApplicationUser> and DbConnection, are respectively an interface and abstract class and cannot be constructed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container, invalidoperationexception, user-management

If I surf to `http://localhost:58472/Account/Register` I've this exception

> **`System.InvalidOperationException:`** The current type, `IUserStore<ApplicationUser>`, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Here is my code:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    { }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(
        IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, 
        IOwinContext context) 
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(
            new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>())
        );

        // other code
        return manager;   
    }
}
```

and here is the code into the controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(
        ApplicationUserManager userManager,
        ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? 
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _signInManager = value;
        }
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? 
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
}
```

So you can see if you read my code, I've nothing changed to the original code when you create a new MVC project, but I've got the error above. What did I wrong?

I've well made a new controller named `ProfileController` with the same code as in my second code block but without the `ApplicationSignInManager` because I don't need that.

I also use an Unity container to register and manage the services. Here is the code:

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IGenericRepo<Category>, GenericRepo<Category>>();
        container.RegisterType<ICategoryService, CategoryService>();
        //container.RegisterType<IUser, ApplicationUser>(); 

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}
```

If I uncomment the line in code above, there aren't any difference when I run the site.

---

**Update:**

By a comment by @Jay I've added this code in the Unity manager.

```
container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
```

Now I've got this exception:

> **`System.InvalidOperationException`:** The current type, `System.Data.Common.DbConnection`, is an abstract class and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Here is some information from the stack trace:

1. `InvalidOperationException`

   > An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type `AccountController`. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

   Yes, I've got a paramaterless public constructor.
2. `ResolutionFailedException`

   > Resolution of the dependency failed, type = `"AccountController"`, name = `"(none)"`.

So I've added this line in the Unity manager:

```
container.RegisterType<IDbConnection, DbConnection>();
```

But I've still have the same exception.

> The current type, `System.Data.Common.DbConnection`...

---

**Update:**

By a comment by @RandyLevy I've tried this, helping by this question [Configure Unity DI for ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927785/configure-unity-di-for-asp-net-identity):

1. Adding this to the `AccountController`:

   ```
   // two fields added
   private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
   private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

   // constructor added
   public AccountController(
       IUserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore, 
       IRoleStore<IdentityRole> roleStore, 
       ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
   {
       _userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
       _roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
       SignInManager = signInManager; // I need this
   }

   public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager // I need this
   {
       get
       {
           return _signInManager ?? 
               HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
       }
       private set
       {
           _signInManager = value;
       }
   }

   public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager // replace by other property 
                                                   // type of ApplicationUserManager 
   {
       get
       {
           return _userManager ?? 
               HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
       }
       //private set // comment this because _usermanager is readonly.
       //{
       //    _userManager = value;
       //}
   }

   //public ApplicationUserManager UserManager // replaced by the property type of 
   //                                          // UserManager<ApplicationUser>
   //{
   //    get
   //    {
   //        return _userManager ?? 
   //            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
   //    }
   //    private set
   //    {
   //        _userManager = value;
   //    }
   //}
   ```
2. Adding this into UnityManager:

   ```
   InjectionConstructor accountInjectionConstructor = 
       new InjectionConstructor(new ApplicationDbContext());

   container.RegisterType<AccountController>();
   container.RegisterType<IController, Controller>();

   container.RegisterType
       <IRoleStore<IdentityRole>, RoleStore<IdentityRole>>
       (accountInjectionConstructor); // on this line

   container.RegisterType
       <IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>
       (accountInjectionConstructor);
   ```

But I've got this error (no run time exception) on the line with the comment:

> The type `RoleStore<IdentityRole>` cannot be used as type parameter `TTo` in the generic type or method below:
>
> ```
> UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>
>     (IUnityContainer, params InjectionMember[])
> ```
>
> There is no implicit reference conversion from `RoleStore<IdentityRole>` to `IRoleStore<IdentityRole>`.

Comment: are you missing a register type for IUserStore<ApplicationUser>?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927785/configure-unity-di-for-asp-net-identity may help.

Comment: @Jay: Thanks, for the hint but I've now an other exception. More information in my question.

Comment: Look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288506/how-to-inject-applicationusermanager-with-unity/32299022#32299022) question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution for my problem. I've add this code into the Unity manager.

```
container.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

Comment: I only started getting the error that the OP was getting after I installed Unity. Seems to have something to do with Unity's dependency resolver not working with the native Identity functionality. Registering these types fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

Update for H. Pauwelyn answer. The original problem for this is that Unity tries to call the constructor with two parameters.

```
public AccountController(
    ApplicationUserManager userManager,
    ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
    SignInManager = signInManager;
}
```

The following line will tell Unity to call the parameterless constructor instead and won't need anything else. This worked for me.

```
container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, one can just remove the constructor from `AccountController` with `[ApplicationUserManager userManager,ApplicationSignInManager signInManager]` and just leave a parameterless constructor (or one with your unity resolved dependencies) since `UserManager` and `SignInManager` both resolve themselves when called...