# Injecting UserManager into CookieAuthenticationProvider fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity, owin

I am trying to log users out if their security stamp changes, but `SecurityStampValidator`never checks the security stamp.
By using the code from [SecurityStampValidator.cs](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/SecurityStampValidator.cs) I have found that `GetUserManager` from this call `var manager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<TManager>();` always returns null.

I am using Unity for Dependency Injection. See:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    CookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie))
        }
    };
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(CookieOptions);
}
```

.

```
unity.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
unity.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
unity.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

**Question:** How do I inject the user manager correctly or wire up the OWIN context correctly?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32299022/) and [this blog post](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/).

Comment: NightOwl888 Thanks a lot, your comment brought me a little closer. 
I've added `app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>())` to my `ConfigureAuth` and it almost works.
It works with the first call to `ConfigureAuth` but on subsequent calls I get a _System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'ApplicationUserManager'_ error.
Any idea how to fix this lifetime issue?